# making duplicate entries without ids using django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a django dashboard where the users can upload their experience certificates.

The problem is the certification section sends duplicate entries to the django view with empty ids and the logic in the views make duplicate entries in thedatabase.

The problem I found that the form is sending duplicate entris without the ids.

certificate.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {% for c in cert %}

                    <input type="text" name="id" value="{{c.id}}">
                           <label>Month</label>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-value" name = "month" value = "{{c.month}}">

                              <label>Year</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-value" name = "year" value = "{{c.year}}">
                                <label>Company</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" id="field-value" name = "company">
                                 {% if c.company %}
                                <option value = "{{c.company}}">{{c.company}}</option>
                                {% endif %}
                                <option value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
                                <option value="TEDx">TEDx</option>
                                <option value="Business Standard">Business Standard</option>
                                <option value="EF Standard English Test">EF Standard English Test</option>
                               <option value="Open2Study">Open2Study</option>
                               <option value="eMarketing Institute">eMarketing Institute</option>
                               <option value="Amazon">Amazon</option>
                               <option value="Airbnb">Airbnb</option>
                               <option value="Adobe">Adobe</option>
                               <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
                               <option value="Intel">Intel</option>
                               <option value="eBay">eBay</option>
                               <option value="Beats">Beats</option>
                              </select>

                              <label>Title</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-value" name = "title" value="{{c.title}}">


                             <label>Certificate</label>
                             <input type="file" class="form-control" id="field-value" name = "img" value="{{c.img}}"> 
                             {% endfor %}
                             <button type="submit" name = "cert-sec" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                             <button type="reset" class="btn btn-dark">Reset</button>
                                </form>
```

views.py

```
elif 'cert-sec' in request.POST:
            idi = request.POST.getlist('id')
            month = request.POST.getlist('month')
            year = request.POST.getlist('year')
            company = request.POST.getlist('company')
            title = request.POST.getlist('title')
            img = request.POST.getlist('img')
            print(idi)
            print(len(title))
            for i in range(len(title)):
                certi = Certification(month = month[i], year = year[i], company = company[i], title = title[i], img=img[i])
                if idi[i] is None or idi[i] is '':
                    certi.save()
                elif idi[i] is not None and certi in cert:
                    cer = Certification.objects.get(id = idi[i])
                    #print(edi.id)
                    cer.month = month[i]
                    cer.year = year[i]
                    cer.company = company[i]
                    cer.title = title[i]
                    cer.img = img[i]
            return redirect('homepage')
```

please need immediate help. Thank you.

Comment: "please need immediate help." => sorry but we're not a free support service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that uniqueness can be defined by using the title, img and company together, you can do something like this:

```
elif 'cert-sec' in request.POST:
            idi = request.POST.getlist('id')
            month = request.POST.getlist('month')
            year = request.POST.getlist('year')
            company = request.POST.getlist('company')
            title = request.POST.getlist('title')
            img = request.POST.getlist('img')
            print(idi)
            print(len(title))
            comp_list = []
            for i in range(len(title)):
                combined_str = company[i]+title[i]+img[i]
                if combined_str in comp_list:
                    continue
                comp_list.append(combined_str)
                certi = Certification(month = month[i], year = year[i], company = company[i], title = title[i], img=img[i])
                if idi[i] is None or idi[i] is '':
                    certi.save()
                elif idi[i] is not None and certi in cert:
                    cer = Certification.objects.get(id = idi[i])
                    #print(edi.id)
                    cer.month = month[i]
                    cer.year = year[i]
                    cer.company = company[i]
                    cer.title = title[i]
                    cer.img = img[i]
            return redirect('homepage')
```

Comment: I found the mistake was in my original code. I have an hidden input field with the same name which i created earlier but forgot to delete.